# Bootstrap collapse navbar not opening fully

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have been stuck with this little problem but I can't seem to find the solution to this.

I'am pretty new to bootstrap and as I was programming the header with the navigation I ran into a problem that I can't seem to fix.
I hope you guys could give me a helping hand.

The problem is this:
When I resize my window to the point that the menu collapses I get the nice icon 3 bar box.
That part is working like a charm.
but whenever I click on it the menu slides open to the last menu item, than jumps back up and you can only see 1,5 menu items.
Also there appears a scrollbar to the side which I can use to scroll through the menu with.

Here is my navigation code & style:

```
<header>

    <!-- NAVBAR
    ===========================================-->

        <nav class="navbar-wrapper">

            <div class="navbar navbar-collapsed-sm navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">

                <div class="container" >

                    <div class="navbar-header">

                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" >
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">navbar<span>brand</span>.nl</a>

                    </div> <!-- navbar-header -->

                    <nav class="navbar-collapse navbar-header-collapse collapse">

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
                            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
                            <li><a href="aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul> <!-- nav -->

                    </nav> <!-- navbar collapse -->

                </div> <!-- container -->

            </div> <!-- navbar -->

        </nav> <!-- navbar-wrapper -->

    </header> <!-- header -->
```

Here is the css

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #FFF !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -mox-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-width: 2px;
    width: 46px;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
 .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus{
    border-color: #f79123 !important;
    background-color: #f79123;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}

ul.nav {
    margin: 21px 0 0 0;
    height: 39px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul.nav li a {
    margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    background: none;
}

ul.nav li a:hover {
    background: none;
}

ul.nav li:last-child a {
    margin-right: 9px;
}

ul.nav li.active > a {
    border-bottom : 3px solid #f79123;
    background: none !important;
}
```

hope you can help me.

-- EDIT ---
Here is a screenshot of the problem
https://gyazo.com/29fb5cae04dc5e59fdff06d08d4cf574

-- SOLUTION --
Ok so by searching in and searching I just couldn't think straight anymore, or at least so it seems.
I found that further in my css I have had a height for the UL element.
That was set later on in the document which probably was some left over code from earlier trail and error.
That was the reason why the menu collapsed to a certain height.

Thanks to Shehary I found it.

Thank you all for trying to help!
Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you set up JSFIDDLE for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `height` from here

```
ul.nav {
    margin: 21px 0 0 0;
    height: 39px; <---Remove this
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

To

```
ul.nav {
    margin: 21px 0 0 0;  
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vx451nhp/2/)

Comment: For a moment I was like "i'm stupid" but after trying it did not help it.
ps. when I ran you fiddle script WITH the height it did not give me the same result.

I added a screenshot link to gyazo so you can see what happens

Comment: i said remove the height, in the fiddle tell me if the full dropdown menu not showing?

Comment: In the jsfiddle link you postes in you answer you removed the hight and the menu works but so I tried to recreate my problem in your script by adding back the height but it did not gave me the same problem I am having. I did however remove it from my style but that also did not solve the problem.

Comment: share your site link if it's not local host  something is causing the menu to collapse so with limited information you provided it's even hard to guess

Comment: Thank you for the help.
Through your suggestion of removing the height I found it further down in my css as left over code.
Accepted your answer and mentioned you in the edit on the op :) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to remove scroll-bar that is coming up when you re-size and expand navbar in a smaller screen sizes.

Do do so, you need to change in CSS as below:

```
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mht59mfn/)

Comment: Sadly this did not work.
It made sense when I saw it in action but for some reason when the menu slides down it gets to the height of the menu and than jumps back.
See my edit in the main question for a screenshot of the problem

Comment: May be you are changing other code as well. I have created fiddle using your code only.

Comment: I would suggest update your question with your JSFIDDLE for clear understanding! Thanks.